# Hook doesn't rerender component

Tags: reactjs, components, render, react-hooks

I'm using React with React-Router-Dom and I don't know why my child component (functional component) does not re-render when the URL change. And I don't know why, when I visit a dynamic page for the first time, the `console.log(url)`fired 3 times ?

My child component :

```js
import React from "react";
import { useFetch } from "./hooks";

function Page(props) {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" + props.match.url;
  console.log(url);

  const [data, loading] = useFetch(url);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        "Loading..."
      ) : (
        <>
          <h1>{data.title}</h1>
          <p>{data.body}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
export default Page;
```

A sandbox is available here for more complete example : https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-mahavira-5ktrk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your child component re-renders, but it uses old data from the previous render. This happens because you don't pass `url` as a dependency in `useEffect` hook. And it will better to move `fetchUrl` function inside `useEffect` (if you don't want to use it in other places), because now `eslint` gives an error:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchUrl'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Here how it should look:

```
function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUrl() {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchUrl();
  }, [url]);
  return [data, loading];
}
```

"And I don't know why, when I visit a dynamic page for the first time, the console.log(url)fired 3 times ?"

This happens because your component rerenders 3 times:

1. When it mounts.
2. When your hook calls `setData(json)`.
3. When your hook calls `setLoading(false)`.

Here working example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/condescending-wildflower-v8m4c

Comment: Thank you for this very instructive answer @andrii

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same problem, but in my fetchData, I pass the fetch function (as 'fetchFunction', replacing 'fetch(url)' in this example) directly. If I put the fetchFunction function in the dependancies array, then it creates an inifinite loop.. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: @Cedo you could use `useMemo` hook to store your `fetchFunction`. Here an example (look at `useFetchVersion2`)
https://codesandbox.io/embed/angry-mcclintock-zvvbq

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko thank you. That's what I did, but with useCallback. It fixes the infinite loop.